# Boost future continuations (then) deadlock

Tags: c++, boost, future, boost-thread, continuations

I'm currently using Boost 1.55 on Windows with `BOOST_THREAD_VERSION=2`, `BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE`, and `BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION`.

In a unit test the continuation seems to be behaving itself, but in the real code it deadlocks.

The basic code structure looks like this on the producer side:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> Dictionary;

struct Operation
{
    std::unique_ptr<boost::promise<Dictionary>> m_promise;

    boost::future<Dictionary> Start(const Dictionary& data)
    {
        m_promise.reset(new boost::promise<Dictionary>());
        // pass off work to something else
        //   it runs asynchronously then calls Complete
        return m_promise->get_future();
    }

    void Complete(const Dictionary& result)
    {
        m_promise->set_value(result);
        m_promise.reset();
    }
};
```

And the consumer side looks like this:

```
m_Operation.Start(data).then([=](boost::future<Dictionary> f)
{
    // ...
    DoSomething(f.get());
});
return true;
```

The continuation does get called, but `f.get()` blocks indefinitely, as does `set_value`.

As far as I can tell, one thread is blocked inside `promise::set_value` (specifically in `future_async_shared_state_base::join()`), while the other is blocked in `future::get()` (specifically the mutex in `shared_state_base::wait()`).

(It looks like the thread that is in `set_value()` is trying to destroy the continuation after acquiring the same mutex that `get()` is blocked on.)

Is this a bug that's fixed in a later version of Boost, am I using an unsupported configuration, or am I doing something else wrong?

I don't want anything involved to block, ever, for any reason.  It should just be a simple callback & handover.

Also I'm puzzled why the continuation executes on a separate thread, instead of executing inside `set_value`.  None of the possible launch policies seem to support running the continuation synchronously, which I would have thought would be the natural default (this is how .NET Tasks behave after all).  I'd really prefer it not spin up a new thread just to run the continuation, since this just ultimately posts work to an Asio service anyway.

Or are futures just the wrong model for this sort of thing?  I've tried making an Asio async method instead but quickly get lost in the boilerplate.